# AS400 querying with Golang JDBC

Tags: go, jdbc, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I tried using the ODBC driver but it says error communicating due to protocol issue on "TCPIP". Upon further checking, I realize that for AS400 I Series, it requires a license to communicate with ODBC driver. However, it's too expensive and thus I'm trying to find a way to do it with JDBC

May I know has anyone done it?

Answer (score 3):

ODBC, OLEDB, and .NET drivers are licensed as part of the base OS.  There's no additional fee.  Whomever owns the system you are connecting to should be able to get them to you.

JDBC drivers are available as part of the open source [Jtopen toolkit](http://jt400.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: If you are being charged you are probably using DB2 Connect which is a general purpose DB2 connectivity solution for mainframe, IBM i, Linux/Unix/Windows. You don't need it for DB2 on i (AS/400) specifically; as Charles says, there are free of charge options.

Comment: The Db2 connect driver is free to use with LUW...but you have to pay extra to use it with the mainfram (Z) or midrange IBM i :/

Comment: Indeed. I think that's why people get led down the garden path - they connect free of charge to LUW and understandably assume the same will apply to other DB2's.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use ODBC with the IBM i Access ODBC driver instead of the Db2 Connect driver? The IBM i Access driver has no licensing required. There seem to be a couple Golang odbc interfaces: [go-odbc](https://github.com/alexbrainman/odbc) and [mgodbc](https://bitbucket.org/miquella/mgodbc/src/default/).

See the "Optional platform-specific packages" section [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg3T1026805) for info on obtaining the driver.